# Fish shell: Alias per directory basis

Tags: fish

Currently my team uses Git a.w.a Mercurial for various projects, So I am here to define my own vcs commands to make common things seamless between different projects/directories (git & hg).

How do I achieve this in fish shell? So that alias can trigger corresponding git or hg commands per directory/subdirectory basis.

Comment: Your question is underspecified. It is trivial to use the `$PWD` variable to decide if you are in a git or mercurial project directory and act accordingly. Frankly, I think what you're trying to do is going to cause more problems than it solves. However, if you need help with fish script syntax please show us what you have tried and we'll be happy to provide guidance.

Comment: Looks like you don't have much idea on what is being asked, Let me know if you need any specific part requires bit explanation/leave it to more informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the current git branch by running:

```
set git_branch (git symbolic-ref HEAD ^/dev/null | sed -e 's|^refs/heads/||')
```

and the current hg branch with:

```
set hg_branch (hg branch)
```

Then simply check which one is truthy, and proceed from there:

```
if test "$git_branch"
    git $argv
else if test "$hg_branch"
    hg $argv
else
    echo "[X] Not in a VCS directory"
    return 1
end
```

If you actually want to write a whole suite of VCS commands that are git/hg agnostic that requires a big more work to translate all the equivalent commands and map the arguments, etc.

This is generally not a good idea though, you're obscuring the actual behavior of the underlying system.  It's better just to show the developer which type of repo you're in, or use a real compatibility layer like [hg-git](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgGit).

Answer (score 0):

Your functions could use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and the respective one for Mercurial to check whether it is inside Git or HG folder. And depending on the result you can decide what to execute.